# Error on calling Snowflake stored procedure from tDBrow in Talend

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, talend

I am getting below error message while executing a Snowflake stored procedure from tDBrow in Talend.
​
The same stored procedure executes fine when executed from Snowflake Web UI. Could you advise why I am getting scoped transaction error when executing from Talend but not from Web UI.

> ERROR:
> Stored procedure execution error: Scoped transaction started in stored procedure is incomplete and it was rolled back.

Comment: Are you running the SP using the same Snowflake role in both Talend and the WebUI?

Comment: you should ensure that you do not start a transaction before your command (or close an existing one). Could you post your stored procedure that you are trying to play .

Comment: @NickW, Yes I use the same roles.

Comment: The problem is solved. When the procedure is called from Talend, the transaction starts before execution of the procedure and it finishes after the execution. I should have explicitly defined the scope of transaction inside the procedure. Therefore I added these 2 lines at the beginning and end of the procedure ( before return) respectively:             snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "BEGIN TRANSACTION"}).execute(); snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "COMMIT"}).execute();

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved. When the procedure is called from Talend, the transaction starts before execution of the procedure and it finishes after the execution.

I should have explicitly defined the scope of transaction inside the procedure. Therefore, I added these two lines at the beginning and end of the procedure (before return) respectively:

```
snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "BEGIN TRANSACTION"}).execute(); 
snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "COMMIT"}).execute();
```

Comment: Would you please show your code (of the procedure)?